# OpenCV Erosion / Dilation erroneous output for empty structuring element?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

If one erodes an image by zeros(3,3) structuring element, it should be all 1s, but in case of OpenCV, it returns the image. Similarly, dilation of image by zeros(3,3) structuring element return image itself instead of all 0s.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=erode#erode) says:

> - element – structuring element used for dilation; if `element=Mat()` , a 3x3 rectangular structuring element is used

If you take a look at the implementation, you will see that in case of empty kernel the `ksize` will be 3x3 inside of [`morphOp()` #1683](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/morph.cpp#L1683):

```
Size ksize = !kernel.empty() ? kernel.size() : Size(3,3);
```

This one also works for me:

```
cv::Mat input = cv::Mat::eye(10, 10, CV_8UC1);
cv::Mat output;

cv::erode(input, output, cv::Mat());
```

Comment: My bad, I meant zeros(3,3) kernel rather than no kernel.